# combining IF, AND, OR expressions in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, logical-operators

I have written the following function in google sheets in order to add "ID" to a column:

```
=if(and(E2>43%, E2<57%, C2=2016), "ID", " ")
```

I would like to add another logical operator, OR, to this. I would like to add "ID" if the following conditions are met, OR if the conditions above are met:

```
E2 >57%, C2=2016, J2=""
```

Column J has names written in it. What I'm trying to say with J2="" is that the space is not blank. I don't care about what the name is, just that there is text written. I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
=if(or(and(E2>43%, E2<57%, C2=2016),AND(E2>57%, C2=2016, J2=""), "ID", " "))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=IF(or(and(B1>43%, B1<57%, A1=2016),and(B1 >57%, A1=2016,istext(E1))), "ID",)
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQ_GHEc0BVtMRSpe0DCRTtq7PNWqy1FGtu2rVypUUso/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Rows 1, 7, and 16 should have ID in column C if done correctly.

Comment: based on the columns your data is in the sample sheet, I edited my answer up top for you,so you may need to adjust the column letters as needed for your actual data, but this formula works